# AWS CDK IAM Federated and User IamRoleAccess?

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

i want to know how i can set an assume role policy document to something more complex than a service...

this is what i found till now and maybe this will work:

```
this.TestRole = new iam.Role(this, "Test", {
    assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("ec2.amazonaws.com"),
    roleName: "TestRole"
})
```

But i want to add something like this:

```
"AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "sts:AssumeRole"
                        ],
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::account1:role/Role1",
                                "arn:aws:iam::account2:role/Role2"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"
                        ],
                        "Principal": {
                            "Federated": {
                                some sub and so on
                            }
                        },
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "SAML:aud": some saml stuff
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I have no clue how to achieve this... can you help me?

Ok, its possible to do something like this:

```
this.TestRole = new iam.Role(this, "Test", {
        assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(new cdk.FnSub("arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:saml-provider/SAMLIDP"), {
            "StringEquals": {
                "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
            }
        }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"),
        roleName: parent.getApplicationName().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + parent.getApplicationName().slice(1)
    })
```

that was easy :-/ But now i want to add the two roles with action sts:AssumeRole - i don't know how to add another principal...

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently not possible. Please upvote this GitHub issue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/1201

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/1377 delivered the fix we need. You can now use `aws_iam.CompositePrincipal` to add multiple Principle including service Principles.

For example, in Python for a Data Pipeline Role:

```
pipeline_role = aws_iam.Role(
    scope=self, id='pipeline-role',
    role_name='pipeline',
    assumed_by=aws_iam.CompositePrincipal(
        aws_iam.ServicePrincipal('datapipeline.amazonaws.com'),
        aws_iam.ServicePrincipal('elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`iam.RoleProps#assumedBy`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-iam.html#@aws-cdk/aws-iam.RoleProps.assumedBy) mentions that you can access the assume policy using the [`iam.Role#assumeRolePolicy`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-iam.html#@aws-cdk/aws-iam.Role.assumeRolePolicy) attribute. You could try something like the following:

```
this.TestRole = new iam.Role(this, 'Test', {
  assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(/*...*/)
  /* ... */
});
this.TestRole.assumeRolePolicy.addStatement(
  new iam.PolicyStatement().allow()
                           .addAction('sts:AssumeRole')
                           .addAwsPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::account1:role/Role1')
                           .addAwsPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::account2:role/Role2')
);
```